# Error con aplicación bluetooth en React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Hola a todos actualmente estoy intentando utilizar una aplicación que encontré de bluetooth en `react native` https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager, ya seguí todos los pasos que indica para poder utilizarla incluso utilicé el `npm install, update, npm install expo`, pero al utilizar `expo start` me tira error

> Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
> Error: react-native is not installed. Please run `npm install` or `yarn` in your project directory.
> Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya busqué en internet sobre el error pero no me funciona nada, alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: se logro solucionar?puedes intentar borrando la carpeta de node_modules y volviendo a ejecutar npm install...o quizas sea problema de versiones?

Comment: me tome el itempo de crear un proyecto con expo y me ha funcionado sin problema,en mi package.json tengo la dependencia Expo:38.0.8,React:16.11.0,react-native: sdk-38.0.2  y mi version de node es 10.16.3

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad soy nuevo con React Native apenas y sé lo básico, podrías decirme como poner exactamente el json de esas dependencias?

Comment: O ya de otra forma exactamente cuales fueron los pasos que seguiste para hacer funcionar la app correctamente?

Comment: la dependecias que aparecen en nuestro package.json son las que instalamos por npm,por lo cual cuando hacemos un npm install pues instalamos todo lo que este contiene,no hay forma de instalar por aparte tales dependencias ps para eso hacemos npm install

Comment: los pasos que segui fue crear un proyecto nuevo de forma normal `expo init nombreProyecto`,luego ejecutarlo para ver que se instalo,parar la ejecucion instalar la dependencia de bluetooh y volver a correr y listo

Comment: Listo ya me funcionó gracias!, la verdad estaba haciendo las cosas de otra forma

Comment: ok,puedes poner lo que hiciste en las respuestas para que la pregunta ayude a los otros en otro momento